# Python Mock abstract class methods

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, abstract-class

I have an abstract class that I am using with the template pattern and some children that implement specific methods.

```py
class TemplateClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def special_process_1():
        pass

    def common_process(): 
        do_something()
    
    def common_filter():
        filter_something()

    def __call__():
        self.common_filter()
        self.special_process_1()
        self.common_process()
    

class classA(TemplateClass):
    def special_process_1():
        something_A_needs()


class classB(TemplateClass):
    def special_process_1():
        something_B_needs()
```

Now, I would like to test the `__call__` method, but I am not sure what would be the best way. I think the best would be if I could test on the template so that I don't need to replicate test for `classA` and `classB`. However, I am not sure how to do it.

I have tried to test the template as follows:

```py
@fixture
def template_mock():
    with patch("TemplateClass.__abstractmethods__", set()):
        t = TemplateClass()
        t.special_process_1 = MagicMock(return_value=False)
        yield t
```

The problem with the above is that on the tests, mypy would complain about `template_mock.special_process_1` being a callable instead of a mock, so it does not have any `return_value` attribute.

Would be open to what other alternatives are there or if it makes sense at all to be testing this on the base class

Comment: You don't need a mock. Just set `TemplateClass.special_process_1 = lambda: False`.

Comment: I did a mock because would like to do `mock.assert_called()`?